# How to locate text on a buffered Image

Tags: java, ocr, bufferedimage

I need to analyse a Buffered Image and locate the X and Y coordinates of a certain word or phrase.
How will I accomplish this, where should a start. I have taken a look at some OCR libraries, but the ones I tried only provide the text and no location where the text can be found.

If you have any advice, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need those coordinates? OCR is usually used to recognize what's on the screen, not locate where it is.... but OpenCV should be able to give you this fine-grained control.

Comment: i need to automate some tasks, and normal macros wont do. i actually need to find the items firs and then click them or drag them or whatever the need, at that time

Comment: ..so this is a hack for automating some game?

Comment: Sounds like you need a smart use of Java `Robot` class ;) no OCR, no need to do overkill.... just scan the screen for the start of the message box's border or something, and work out the absolute positions from there. Unless you're making a professional hack, in which case you really shouldn't be asking these kind of questions.... ;)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

it has screen capture, it has keyboard/mouse manipulation. Go with this.

Comment: Hey shark i am already using Robot to capture the screen and perform mouse and keyboard operations. problem is detecting where to click. i can write it for my screen resolution but then it will be useless on someone else's PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check hOCR output or ResultIterator object of [Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) to obtain recognized word coordinates. Look at the test cases of [Tess4J](http://tess4j.sf.net), a Java JNA wrapper of Tesseract API, for examples with BufferedImage.